# Sorting in functional programming languages

Tags: sorting, functional-programming

I've been learning functional programming for some time, but I haven't read somewhere about sorting with the functional programming languages.

I know the sorting algorithms that are based on value exchanges are hard to implement with the functional idea, but I want to know that are there any sorting algorithms for use in functional programming? What are they?

Thank you.

Comment: The only problem that I know of is that you can't implement an *in-place* algorithm using immutable structures.

Comment: @Goran Jovic: Thanks for the point. I was still thinking in the procedural way. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, you can't do the in-place with immutables in imperative languages either. It's just that imperative languages usually have libraries with mutable structures as default.

Comment: It's *possible* to do an in-place sort on an immutable datastructure as long as you "copy" at each step and the compiler can prove the old values are never used: i.e. using monads.  However, it's not simple: http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/parallel-generic-quicksort-in-haskell.html (disclaimer: Jon Harrop does have an axe to grind with haskell).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a functional language you write a function that given a list returns a sorted list, not touching (of course) the input.

Consider for example merge sorting... first you write a function that given two already sorted lists returns a single sorted list with the elements of both in it. For example:

```
def merge(a, b):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return b
    elif len(b) == 0:
        return a
    elif a[0] < b[0]:
        return [a[0]] + merge(a[1:], b)
    else:
        return [b[0]] + merge(a, b[1:])
```

then you can write a function that sorts a list by merging the resulting of sorting first and second half of the list.

```
def mergesort(x):
    if len(x) < 2:
        return x
    else:
        h = len(x) // 2
        return merge(mergesort(x[:h]), mergesort(x[h:]))
```

About Python syntax:

- `L[0]` is the first element of list `L`
- `L[1:]` is the list of all remaining elements
- More generally `L[:n]` is the list of up to the n-th element, `L[n:]` the rest
- `A + B` if `A` and `B` are both lists is the list obtained by concatenation
- `[x]` is a list containing just the single element `x`

PS: Note that python code above is just to show the concept... in Python this is NOT a reasonable approach. I used Python because I think it's the easiest to read if you know any other common imperative language.

Comment: This is a better solution that larsman's: don't use quicksort, use mergesort.

Comment: h = len(x) should be m = len(x) / 2 but very concise answer. thanks.

Comment: @Yaniv.H: In Python `//` is the integer division operator, not a comment. Comments are introduced by `#`.

Comment: Any ideas on it's runtime complexity?

Comment: @Abhishek: in Python for sure horrible :-) ... for this approach to be reasonable you need linked lists to have merge O(n1+n2) and the split operation is probably better done between odd/even elements (that requires a single pass). In Python lists are implemented as arrays and there is no tail recursion optimization so the merging implementation shown is Very Bad. The code is only for showing the idea of a functional approach to sorting.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some links to sorting algorithms implemented in Haskell:

- [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)
- [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)
- [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Merge sort is often the best choice for sorting linked lists. Functional languages usually operates on lists although I have little knowledge on how most functional languages implements lists. In Common Lisp they are implemented as linked lists and I presume most functional languages do as well.

While quicksort can be written for linked lists it will suffer from poor pivot selection because of random access. While this does not matter on completely random input, on partially or completely sorted input pivot selection becomes very important. Other sorting algorithms may also suffer from the slow random-access performance of linked lists.

Merge sort on the other hand works well with linked lists and it is possible to implement the algorithm such that it only requires some constant of extra space with linked lists.

Comment: You should point out that one of these is head and shoulders better than all the others in a functional world: mergesort.

Comment: @Eamon, I have not heard before that merge sort is the algorithm to use for functional languages. However I have added some to explanation why that might be. If there is anything in particular you are referring to that I have not covered then I am curious!

Comment: Pivot choosing and the combine phase in quicksort in FP languages are slower than in imperative languages, but they are O(n) where n is the size of the part that needs to be sorted in each iteration. Since partitioning that part into 2 parts is also O(n), they only add a constant to the coefficient of the time complexity.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the classic ([pseudo-?](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357))quicksort in Haskell:

```
sort []      =   []
sort (p:xs)  =   sort [x | x<- xs, x <= p]
              ++ [p]
              ++ sort [x | x <- xs, x > p]
```

See, e.g., [c2.com](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuickSortInHaskell) or [LiteratePrograms.org](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28Haskell%29). [Merge sort](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Merge_sort#Haskell) isn't much harder to write and more reliable in practice. The same can be done in Scheme with:

```
(define (sort xs)
  (if (null? xs)
    '()
    (let* ((p (car xs)) (xs (cdr xs)))
      (call-with-values (lambda () (partition (lambda (x) (<= x p)) xs))
                        (lambda (l r)
                          (append (sort l) (list p) (sort r)))))))
```

with [`partition` from SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#partition) (untested code). See also [chapter 4 of R6RS libraries](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-5.html#node_chap_4).

Comment: Looks to me like this will sneak in extra values, as the pivot will be contained in the left sublist.

Comment: It's not. Note that the input list is split into `p` and `xs` by pattern matching. (There may be values equal to `p` in `xs`, of course.)

Comment: Concerning this version of the Quicksort algorithm, Andrei Alexandrescu has something interesting to say in his article ["On Iteration"](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357). Basically, that it's not truly Quicksort, since it doesn't work in-place; and second, that its choice of the pivot element is less than optimal. Recommended reading.

Comment: @larsmans: thanks for the answer. Basically I am using Scheme, and `list` instead of `vector` is the most widely used container. I guess that's a different problem?

Comment: @Ryan Li: in Scheme, much the same algorithms can be implemented as in Haskell, though it will take more boilerplate. You may be able to use linear update procedures in parts of the code to speed it up.

Comment: That's not quicksort: http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357  It isn't in-place, and will *commonly* degenerate to quadratic complexity: don't use!

Comment: @Eamon: I'm not suggesting the OP should *use* this algorithm, it's an *example* of how to implement sorting in FP. The OP should use the algorithm in their language's standard library. That being said, I updated my answer with a reference to Alexandrescu's interesting article, so I hope you'll retract the -1.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can implement imperative, side-effecting sort algorithms in functional languages.

I've implemented a sorting algorithm that operates in-place in a functional programming language called ATS; all mutation is handled by linear types. If you're interested in this kind of thing, drop me a line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably raising this question from the grave but I think a global comparison approach might be useful to some people (in case *we're not sorting numbers* for example). Here is a TypeScript version using ES6:

**TL;DR**

```js
type Comparator<T> = (itemA: T, itemB: T) => number;

const mergeSort = <T>(list: T[], compare: Comparator<T>): T[] => {
  if (list.length <= 1) return list;
  const middleIndex = Math.floor(list.length / 2);
  const listA = mergeSort(list.slice(0, middleIndex), compare);
  const listB = mergeSort(list.slice(middleIndex), compare);
  return merge(listA, listB, compare);
};

const merge = <T>(listA: T[], listB: T[], compare: Comparator<T>): T[] => {
  if (listA.length === 0) return listB;
  if (listB.length === 0) return listA;
  return compare(listA[0], listB[0]) <= 0
    ? [listA[0], ...merge(listA.slice(1), listB, compare)]
    : [listB[0], ...merge(listA, listB.slice(1), compare)];
};
```

---

**Explaination**

We can pass an extra `compare` function to the `mergeSort` function now. This `compare` function has the same definition as in [JavaScript's `Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method's parameter.

For instance, the `number` comparator would be:

```js
const compareNumbers: Comparator<number> = (numberA, numberB) =>
  numberA - numberB;
```

...while a `User` object comparator could be:

```js
const compareUsersByAge: Comparator<User> = (userA, userB) =>
  userA.age - userB.age;
```

...or anything more complicated if need be (e.g. string comparison).